# BatteryChanges status testing in android Mockito

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing, intentfilter

I am facing an issue in the IntentFilter during the test using Mockito. Here is my test Case:

```
@Test
public void shouldBeAbleToObserveBattery(){
    Disposable disposable = ReactiveBattery.observeBatteryChanges(mContext).subscribe(batteryState ->{
            assertThat(batteryState.level(), is(not(-1)));
            assertThat(batteryState.plugged(), is(not(-1)));
            assertThat(batteryState.scale(), is(not(-1)));
    });
}
```

PresenterClass method:

```
@Override
public void observeBattery() {
    getCompositeDisposable().add(ReactiveBattery
            .observeBatteryChanges(getContext())
            .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
            .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
            .subscribe(state -> getBaseView().onBatteryChanged(state)));
}
```

`observeBatteryChanges` and the `receiver`:

```
@Override
    public Observable<BatteryState> observeBatteryChanges(final Context context) {

        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        batteryReceiver = createBatteryChangesReceiver(batterySubject);
        context.registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, filter);

        return batterySubject.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
                .doOnCancel(() -> tryToUnregisterReceiver(context, batteryReceiver))
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .toObservable();
    }

    @NonNull
    private BroadcastReceiver createBatteryChangesReceiver(
            final PublishSubject<BatteryState> subject) {
        return new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
                int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
                int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
                subject.onNext(BatteryState.create(level, scale, plugged, BatteryStatus.of(status)));
            }
        };
    }
```

When i am running the test its showing error in line `final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!

    at android.content.IntentFilter.<init>(IntentFilter.java:144)
```

How can I mock this IntentFilter and BroadcastReceiver to resolve this issue? As i am a newbie in this Mockito testing expecting some help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you didn't mock `android.*` classes, So It tells you that you're using a stub implementation of them.

You can use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) for this purpose. There is a `ShadowContextWrapper` that act like a real wrapper but for testing purposes. For example,
 you can register your `batteryReceiver` like:

```
  private final Context context = RuntimeEnvironment.application;
  private final ShadowContextWrapper shadowContextWrapper = Shadow.extract(context);
  ...
  context.registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: What does shadowContextWrapper object here? Also i am calling the observeBatteryChanges method outside of my application and that registerReceiver is handling from there. So, How can i do this for my case?

Comment: `ShadowContextWrapper` is part of robolectric, instead of `mContext` you must pass the context from robolectric (`RuntimeEnvironment.application`)

Comment: Tried but my receiver is not registering hence its not returning any result. I guess context is not working here.